# How to convert my Data set to Gaussian?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert an Attribute in My data set to Gaussian distribution, but i can't seem to find any formula that i can implement. I don't want to use any Builtin Functions. So is there a formula ? like the one we have for Max-Min normalization?

Comment: Why exactly would you like to do this..?

Comment: Actually, I am doing this assignment for my Intro to Data Science Course, and i am guided to do it. So i am looking for ways.

Comment: From the mean and variance (derived from your data), you can build a gaussian distribution just from the gaussian probability density function. Is that what you need?

Comment: So i should just implement to distribution function? using x as my data?
After implementing that function the mean of my data should be zero and Variance 1?